# TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'build_headers'

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, raspberry-pi3, firebase-admin

Here is the code

```
def stream_handler(message): 
  print(message["event"])
  print(message["path"])
  print(message["data"])
my_stream = db.child("posts").stream(stream_handler)
```

I am getting this error

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner

self.run()

File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run

self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyrebase/pyrebase.py", line 556, in start_stream

self.sse = ClosableSSEClient(self.url, session=self.make_session(), build_headers=self.build_headers)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyrebase/pyrebase.py", line 518, in __init__super(ClosableSSEClient, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sseclient.py", line 48, in __init__self._connect()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyrebase/pyrebase.py", line 522, in _connect
super(ClosableSSEClient, self)._connect()

File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sseclient.py", line 56, in _connectself.resp = requester.get(self.url, stream=True, **self.requests_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in get
return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I have been trying to get live database changed in python raspberry using firebase_Admin 
db.listen,But get this Error Please Help

Comment: You need to post your code, not just the traceback.

Comment: @Barmar yes i posted it

Comment: You're not really using `firebase-admin`. You're using `pyrebase` which is a whole other library.

Comment: yes it is in pyrebase.